# Download a URL containing a token query string

Tags: wget, curl, url

To explain what I want I will give an example (My foreign friends sorry it is in Arabic not English :D ) .

Let's take this [URL](http://3rbup.com/08bc4a030a61c8cf) for example. When you open it a blue square will appear after a 5 second timer. Before pressing this blue button, if you inspect it with your browser, you will notice that the `href` for this button is the same URL followed by a query `?pt=` which appears to be some kind of a token that is generated every time.

If you follow this URL (by pressing the button or copy/paste the URL) it will direct you to a page and again, inspecting the page, more specifically to an element written as (تحميل), the `href` contains the same [URL](http://3rbup.com/08bc4a030a61c8cf) but followed by a query "download_token", which is generated on every time you request the page.

Now you can get the original [URL](http://3rbup.com/08bc4a030a61c8cf) with `wget` and with some parsing you can get the inner URL (the one with the query `?pt=`), but passing the resulting URL from parsing will get the original [URL](http://3rbup.com/08bc4a030a61c8cf) not the page that contains the `download_token`

- I tried `wget` and `curl`
- I tried passing the URL in single and double qoute
- First token contain `%XX` which is a hex representation of an ASCII. I replaced them with the corresponding characters but it did not work.

How to make `wget`, `curl` or any other similar utility to download a URL following its dynamic query? seems like it is parsing the URL with `?pt=` somehow wrong, maybe due to the hex characters? The URL with `download_token` works fine with `wget` (at least in few trials).

My purpose for all this is to automate the similar process for the rest 1200+ links.

Comment: In addition to the GET argument in the URL, the server may be checking for a client side cookie value.... both cURL and wget can use a cookie file exported from your browser - but this would be an extra step...

Comment: Hi @ivanivan , this is interesting, can you please give more details if possible?